# Assistance needed calling a webMethod with JQuery-AJAX 

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json

Please help with my final project in my intro/intermediate programming class.

Using stored procedures,table adapters, and business classes he wants us to populate an ASP.NET gridview with fields from the "Supplier" table (I have this working).

He then wants us to list the products for each supplier using a stored procedure passing a parameter to list prodcuts based on the supplierID. I can do this using ASP.NET objects and visual gridview features(gridview "select" property to pass the parameter, dataobjectsouruces).

But he wants us to use AJAX to retrieve a list of products for each supplier based on selecting the suppliers name from a dropdown list box.

When I run this I keep getting my error function alert.  I also don't know how I would write the AJAX success function to display potentially multiple rows of product information (an array?)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, All the code is below,

Thanks!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            var supplierid = { supplierid: $('#DropDownList1').val() };
            supplierid = JSON.stringify(supplierid);
            alert(supplierid);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: supplierid,
                contentType: "application/JSON",
                url: "MainForm.aspx/getProductDetails",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each((data.d), function(index,m) {
                        $('#output').append('<p><strong>' + m.productid +
                        ' ' + m.productname + ' ' + m.supplierid + ' ' + m.categoryid + ' ' + unitprice + '</strong></p>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (x, e) {
                    alert("The call to the Supplier failed. " + x.responseText);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

MainForm.aspx:

```
Partial Class MainForm
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function getProductDetails(ByVal supplierid As Integer) As List(Of Products)
    Dim prodData As New ProductData
    Return prodData.getProductById(supplierid)
End Function
```

'THIS PART WOULD POPULATE THE DROP DOWN LIST

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim supplierdata As New supplierdata
    DropDownList1.DataSource = supplierdata.getSupplierData()
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "companyname"
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "supplierid"
    DropDownList1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

The "products" and "productData" classes and business function:

```
Public Class Products
    Public Property productid As Integer
    Public Property productname As String
    Public Property supplierid As Integer
    Public Property categoryid As Integer
    Public Property unitprice As Integer
End Class

Public Class ProductData
    Public Function getProductById(ByVal supplierid As Integer) As List(Of Products)
        Dim ProductList As New List(Of Products)
        Dim dt As New DataSet1.GetProductdataBySupplierDataTable
        Dim productRow As DataSet1.GetProductdataBySupplierRow

        //  retrieves the data from the database and loads into the datatable
        // closes the connection at the end.

        Using ta As New DataSet1TableAdapters.GetProductdataBySupplierTableAdapter
            Try
                dt = ta.GetProdcutsbySupplier(supplierid)
                If dt.Count = 0 Then
                     //no matching record found, return false
                    Throw New ApplicationException("Retrieve: No such record")
                Else

                    productRow = dt(0)
                    Dim aProduct As New Products()
                    With aProduct
                        .productid = productRow.productid
                        .productname = productRow.productname
                        .supplierid = productRow.supplierid
                        .categoryid = productRow.categoryid
                        .unitprice = productRow.unitprice
                    End With
                    ProductList.Add(aProduct)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New ApplicationException("Error Getting Members " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
        Return ProductList
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery templating to format data into HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem (the reason you're ending up in the error handler) is that you need to pass a JSON string to the WebMethod:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        // Use a JSON string, not a JavaScript object.
        var supplierid = '{ "supplierid": "' + $('#DropDownList1').val() + '" }';
        supplierid = JSON.stringify(supplierid);
        alert(supplierid);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            // Possible issue: dataType is case sensitive.
            dataType: "json",
            data: supplierid,
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "MainForm.aspx/getProductDetails",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each((data.d), function(index,m) {
                    $('#output').append('<p><strong>' + m.productid +
                    ' ' + m.productname + ' ' + m.supplierid + ' ' + m.categoryid + ' ' + unitprice + '</strong></p>');
                });
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert("The call to the Supplier failed. " + x.responseText);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

See here for more info on that particular error: http://encosia.com/2010/05/31/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/

---

Update:

Another problem you're facing is that Button1 is a submit button, which submit's the page's form when clicked.  So, even though you're starting an AJAX request, the form submission acts as a page refresh before the response comes back, and it's lost.  That's why you haven't been seeing a meaningful error message.

You can avoid that by making a call to preventDefault() within your click handler, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Button1").click(function (evt) {
    // This prevents the form submission from happening.
    evt.preventDefault();

    // The rest of your previous code here...
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but my error handler is still being triggered.  the only difference now is my buttonClick alert text changes from `{"supplierid"":"SomeValue"}` (before your suggested changes) to 
`"{\"supplierid\":\"SomeValue\"}"` ? any ideas?

Comment: That's good.  That's valid JSON now.  What exactly is the error that you're seeing in your error handler?  You should have been getting "Invalid JSON Primitive" before, but now something else.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing as I saw before which is my error function alert: `the call to the supplier has failed`.  I never had an Invalid JSON primitive message

Comment: The invalid JSON bit (the actual server-side error) should have been added by the `x.responseText`.  Are are not receiving any error text at all there?  I'd suggest running this in Firefox, with FireBug installed, then watch the request in the console.  You should be able to see the actual server-side error better there.

Comment: Okay, I see why aren't seeing a useful error message.  The Button1 input is also submitting the page at the same time that it makes the $.ajax() request, which reloads it before the async response comes in.  Updating my answer.

Comment: Also, I led you astray with the JSON quoting.  I didn't notice that you were stringifying the object before passing it to jQuery.  You had it right to begin with.  Sorry about that.